# How come the Maldives accepted Sri Lankan president Gotabaya Rajapaksa's visa, but not the USA?

Tags: united-states, visa, sri-lanka, maldives

This [site](http://www.colombopage.com/archive_22B/Jul13_1657681824CH.php) says (emphasis mine):

> According to the report to BBC, the President has left for the **Maldives**.

> The Hindu newspaper revealed that the United States has **rejected** President Gotabaya Rajapaksa’s recent request for a visa to leave for the U.S.

How come the Maldives accepted Gotabaya Rajapaksa's visa, but not the USA?

Comment: Have you looked at [relations between the Maldives and Sri Lanka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maldives%E2%80%93Sri_Lanka_relations)? The two countries seem closely connected.

Comment: If this forum does not answer then I suggest you try travel forum. I know it is a high-profile politician, but they just seem to know a lot about visas on the other forum.

Comment: @ThomasKoelle, this visa was a political hot potato. Most countries reserve the right to grant or deny visa at the political will of the government, but that is not the category which Travel SE talks about.

Comment: @o.m. there are certainly some questions and answers concerning diplomatic travel over at [Travel.SE].  In this case, I don't know whether the president applied for a diplomatic visa or not, but I do know that if he applied for any other sort of visa it would be refused because a president is _only_ eligible for a diplomatic visa.  If he did apply for a diplomatic visa, well, the granting of such a visa is entirely a political decision, so in the absence of public statements from the US Department of State, all we can do is speculate.

Comment: @phoog, humanitarian visa would also include political decisions.

Comment: @o.m. which visa is that?

Comment: @phoog, depends on the country. In Germany, §23(1) AufenthG. Basically, "*if they government wants somebody in, they can allow it regardless of the paperwork.*"

Comment: @o.m. I thought we were talking about US visas.  I am unaware of a catch-all "humanitarian visa" in US immigration law.  Perhaps they could admit him as a refugee, but there's no visa for that.

Comment: @phoog In the US there is [humanitarian parole](https://www.uscis.gov/forms/explore-my-options/humanitarian-parole)

Comment: The article quotes the "Hindu newspaper", maybe there is more information in that original article

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One explanation could be that the Maldives are repaying an old favor. One of the earliest parties there was the MDP (Maldivian Democratic Party), who were officially founded in exile in Sri Lanka, being at the time banned in the Maldives. In particular, former Maldivian president Mohamed Nasheed was one of the founding members who at the time lived in Sri Lanka.

Comment: This doesn't work unless it was a personal favor by the President